# How to update bar graph in Highcharts without redrawing again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I want to update the bar graph with the data which comes dynamically without re-drawing again the whole graph. [My sample Code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/fhw9mq8b/)

```
  $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked bar chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            reversed: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3]
        }]
    });
});
```

Here if the data in the series comes up dynamically, then how to just increase or decrease the bar width or the count up/down of the specific bars. Also if a another bar adds up or the existing bar is not there in the new data.

Comment: You may use Series.update() for updating whole series, Series.setData() For setting data of your series, chart.addSeries() For adding new Series and Series.addPoint() for adding single point to your series. You can find information about this methods in Highcharts API: http://api.highcharts.com/

Answer (score 0):

Add the following

```
  events: {
                load: function () {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.random();
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 1000);
                }
```

This adds points every second but you could change the interval or the vent itself to say a click event.

So highcharts has a demo that you could check out for this if you need further clarification :

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/

Comment: Hello Alan, This is good but can you please explain how can i update my data if my data in series is updated, here you are changing the data with some functions @Alan

Comment: Are you updating the series data using JS/Jquery?

Comment: this whole file is a child presenter and the data comes up when ever the parent makes and ajax request and the data is passed inside a function of the child presenter( this graph presenter ) @Alan

Comment: The setIntervalfunction changes the data by adding points to the series. You could create a function that traverse all the array data when the call to AJAX is made and adds them to the series using the series.addPoint() function.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-click-to-add/ 
                        
This allows you to add a point on click function. I can't simulate loading AJAX data (I'm not sure how to do it on JSFiddle). But I've commented out some code where you can run a loop to add data.

Comment: This sounds cool and will work i hope .But i want to update data dynamically only if it meet a certain condition( like there will be auto refresh option at the top of the page, if it is made 'on' then only this should work).Is it possible to put a condition or call it from  outside to execute?

Comment: You can do this by changing the event listener. Lets say the refresh button has an id refresh then using Jquery I could do the following :
$('#refresh').click(function() {
//load data here
))
You can change the click to any other event like hover, etc.

Comment: Im not able to reproduce this on  a bar graph which i have shared in the above Fiddle URL @Alan :(

Comment: Sorry this is not working on the stacked bar graphs @Alan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117909/discussion-between-alan-and-k-p).

Comment: Hi @Alan i got this thing done. I used setData method of highcharts